# how to push spark streaming output to oracle

Tags: oracle, spark-streaming, sqoop

i have a a spark streaming program that will aggregate and process data in a window of 15 minutes​. the output of this needs to be pushed to oracle tables.

what would be the best approach here?

if i write my data into hive and then use sqoop to push it to oracle, then i will have to schedule my sqoop job in a certain frequency and sqoop should somehow understand what data it pulled before and what is delta that it should pull from hive now. i am not sure if sqoop can do that.

what would you suggest?

thank you.

Comment: You don't have to write the data to the hive to export to Oracle, You can create a CSV or other delimited file from the data frame and write it to HDFS, based on the timestamps you can isolate the sqoop job to push the delta to Oracle. Let me know if you need more explanation on that, I can post an answer.

Comment: thanks for the response. can you please explain this part a little more technically- "based on the timestamps you can isolate the sqoop job to push the delta to Oracle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also connect to Oracle DB  in Spark
Example:

```
r2.foreachPartition {
it =>
    val conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password)
    val del = conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO tweets (ID,Text) VALUES (?,?) ")
    for (bookTitle <-it)
     {
          del.setString(1,bookTitle.toString)
          del.setString(2,"my input")
          del.executeUpdate
    }
}

OR

val employees = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@//localhost:1521/single", "dbtable" -> "hr.employees"))
```